# Visualizing interference of two waves on the plane

Tags: plotting, animation, physics

I need to make an animation of interfering coherent waves on the plane, that are produced by two sources. I would really appreciate if I am able to change the wavelength.

I am quite new to Wolfram, so I have completely no idea on how to make these "two" waves react to each other and show that to the user.

Comment: Take a look at this Wolfram Demonstration for a start: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/WaveInterference/. You can get the source code of the demonstration as well

Comment: What kind of sources (points, apertures, ...), what kind of time dependence? What have you tried?

Comment: Here's a starting point: ReliefImage[
 `Table[
  Sin[Norm[{x + 4, y}]] + Sin[Norm[{x - 4, y}]],
  {x, -30., 30., .1}, {y, -30., 30, .1}
  ],
 ColorFunction -> "Aquamarine"
 ]`  Also look up `DensityPlot`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you're looking for something like this:

```
wave[x_, y_, x0_, y0_, l_, t_] := 
  Sin[Sqrt[(x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2]/l + t];

Manipulate[
 DensityPlot[
  wave[x, y, d, 0, l1, t l1 l2] + 
   wave[x, y, -d, 0, l2, t l1 l2], {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, 
  Mesh -> 10, PlotPoints -> 50], 
  {d, 5, 20},
  {l1, 5, 20}, 
  {l2, 5, 20}, 
  {t, 0, 1}]
```

`d` controls the distance between sources, `l1` and `l2` changes their wavelengths.
[image: Image of the manipulate object]

Another example

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[
  wave[x, y, d, 0, l1, t l1 l2] + 
   wave[x, y, -d, 0, l2, t l1 l2], {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, 
  Mesh -> 10, PlotPoints -> 100, Contours -> {-0.5, 0.5}], {d, 5, 
  20}, {l1, 5, 20}, {l2, 5, 20}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Another example]

Comment: Thanks. But I want waves to move to see the process of interferrence itself. Do I add "Dynamic" or sth of this kind?

Comment: I didn't include it because it might be kind of slow.

Comment: @MichaelFreimann I've updated it, I just included a additional `Manipulate` field for t (with the right period). Use the `+` then just press play.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I now about the density plot.

Comment: I am now trying to visualize "borders" of the waves, to show their interaction. I have tried using "MeshFunction" but got nothing.

Comment: @MichaelFreimann I don't quite follow your meaning. Perhaps you want a `ContourPlot` instead of a `DensityPlot`? (much slower though)

Comment: I mean it is not distinct enough, quite blurry. I want to show wavefront with drawn lines. So you get not the "real" situation, but "discrete" waves, which is better for understanding.

Comment: @MichaelFreimann OK, increase `PlotPoints` to increase the resolution. If you want lines, there's two things you can do within `ContourPlot`, the first is to plot `wave[..]+wave[..] == 0` instead of just `wave[..]+wave[..]`, the other is similar: use `Contours->{insert values here}` to specify the levels used, I think just using `Contours->{-0.5,0.5}` with `PlotPoints->100` is pretty clear. All this is documented in the help section of `ContourPlot`

Comment: @MichaelFreimann see updated answer